# What do polling experts have to say about Rassmussen Reports using a known white supremacist slogan in a poll?

Tags: united-states, polling

Poor Scott Adams of Dilbert's fame did [a monumental career seppuku](https://www.reuters.com/world/us/dilbert-cartoon-dropped-after-racist-rant-by-creator-scott-adams-2023-02-26/) by going on a rant about Black people.  This was motivated by his interpretation of the findings of a poll by [Rassmussen Reports](https://www.rasmussenreports.com/public_content/lifestyle/questions/january_2023/questions_okay_to_be_white_february_13_15_2023).

> 1* Do you agree or disagree with this statement:  “It’s OK to be white.”
>
> 2* Do you agree or disagree with this statement:  “Black people can be racist, too.”

Thing is the exact phrase used in question 1 is a well known, long standing meme by white nationalist/supremacists [ref: It's Okay To Be White | ADL](https://www.adl.org/resources/hate-symbol/its-okay-be-white).

> The phrase “It’s Okay To Be White” is a slogan popularized in late 2017 as a trolling campaign by members of the controversial discussion forum 4chan.
>
> The original flier campaign occurred in late October 2017 and a similar campaign took place at the same time in 2018, but use of the phrase has extended far beyond the flier campaigns.

A previous question asked about Scott Adams, the poll and the results of that poll.  This is not this question.

Rather, reputable polling organization live and die by the quality of their questions.  Rassmussen Reports, while accused of [aligning perhaps too much with US conservatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rasmussen_Reports), would seem to aim for credibility as a provider of polls.

Skipping all the Dilbert brouhaha, as well as the results of the poll, **what has come to light in how Rassmussen, ostensibly a major polling organization used, 100% verbatim, a [historically known](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22it%27s%20ok%20to%20be%20white%22&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A%2Ccd_max%3A2%2F1%2F2023&tbm=) white supremacist meme**?  And a question, I would add, that even without the white supremacist association, seems to be unclear/deficient in determining whether or not a respondent is actually prejudiced against white people.  Question phrasing being a core competency of a polling organization.

What does Rassmussen Reports and major polling organizations have to say about that?

No, I am not interested in hearing the [interpretation that it was trolling](https://twitter.com/normative/status/1630062996645978113).  While I am somewhat sympathetic to that interpretation, I am more interested in how **is this is being discussed by Rassmussen's peers.  And how Rassmussen defends using that particular question.**  Has anyone neutral with credentials in the field given a more sympathetic explanation on this choice?

Because, to me, a major polling organization dropping the ball like this, and the *expert* coverage around this failure, is *waaaay* more interesting than Scott Adams going on a rant (which did put this idiocy on the map).

Comment: Rereading the question, in not sure there is political value in asking this as there is no reason to have civilians launch investigations into how a civilian company operates, especially if there aren't any legal problems. There likely isn't going to be an answer to this question because no one would conduct such a valueless inquiry.

Comment: Voting to Close as this doesn't really deal with "governments, policies and political processes" - sure dirty politics are part of political processes and there are polling organisations that aren't honest ... but do we really want to be discussing the credibility of polling agencies here?

Comment: @sfxedit for many democracies and US in particular, polling is a very significant aspect of how elections are run, but certainly "which polling agencies do you think are credible" won't fly. However, "Are there widely-used metrics for polling quality and utility, and how does Rassmussen rank?" might be a viable quesiton.

Comment: @uhoh Thanks for educating me on something I wasn't fully aware of. I guess from a US political perspective this question may be pertinent. I still doubt polling questions may be better off at say [Stats.SE](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) or something similar ...?

Comment: @sfxedit No I don't think so. The issue here is the exact wording of the poll's question(s) and how to *interpret* the resulting numbers and divining political insights from them. Statistics is orthogonal to that. Polling is a pillar of the US political institution.

Answer (score 4):

Well, I'm not sure one can undisputedly meet the criteria for answering the 1st half of the Q, given the usual accusations of left-wing bias against the academia and media being professed in the (right-wing part of the) US. But since you're also asking about Rasmussen's response to that, it's probably fair enough to have some leeway there.

So yeah, the *Washington Post* has coverage like:

> “Anyone who did know the history of it or who had a suspicion about the history of it might react to that Rasmussen question with some skepticism,” said Nicholas Valentino, a political scientist at the University of Michigan who studies racial attitudes and public emotions. “And that wouldn’t be a sign that they didn’t like White people.”
>
> In a video that Rasmussen posted on Twitter alongside the survey results, head pollster Mark Mitchell presented the question as a good-faith effort to capture public opinion — something he claimed Rasmussen is unique in doing. (“The reality of American public opinion does not match what you’ve being told in the news, at schools or colleges, by corporations and by your public officials.”) Mitchell suggested that mainstream journalists would hesitate to report on the result of the question because it “conclusively undermines the current racial orthodoxy.”
>
> “All we did was ask very simple questions that should be uncontroversial, and we are reporting on what Americans told us, nothing more,” Mitchell said in the video. While Adams cited the number of skeptical Black respondents to raise race-based alarm, Mitchell cited the majority of respondents of all races who approve of the phrase to take aim at liberal-leaning groups such as the Southern Poverty Law Center for designating it a problematic phrase.
>
> In recent years, Rasmussen has shifted from serving primarily as a right-leaning polling firm to more actively amplifying conservative causes, with a website featuring commentary from conservative and libertarian pundits. In the video about the recent survey question, Mitchell also hyped polling results that he said showed “nearly half the country is concerned that vaccines are causing a significant number of unexplained deaths.” (The U.S. Centers for Disease Control and Prevention has said there is no evidence that coronavirus vaccines are causing deaths.) On Twitter, the firm also elevated misinformation about alleged fraud in the 2020 presidential election and highlighted conspiracy theories suggesting that the Jan. 6 insurrection was a “set-up.”

I.e. they get some academic to lambast Rasmussen, quote Rasmussen's' claim to innocence [in response], but at the same time their self-professed agenda is illustrated slightly more broadly, although maybe that's what someone would call a [hatchet job](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/78384/why-has-libertarianism-achieved-so-little-as-a-political-ideology-in-the-world#comment334047_78384)? (What else did you expect?)

Comment: Totally aside, a polling firm quoting Stalin on the relevance of those counting votes has a double funny read, IMHO https://www.thewrap.com/rasmussen-invokes-stalin-suggests-pence-overturn-electoral-votes/ (or even triple funny in this context, given that it's a quote with disputed attribution.)

Comment: "...might react to that Rasmussen question with some skepticism ... wouldn’t be a sign that they didn’t like White people.”
This doesn't work really for me, because what evil interpretation could there be if everyone answered that yes, it's ok to be white?  Would the white supremacists like that outcome?  I don't really think so.  They need it to look like white people are hated.  Everyone who answers "No" is playing right into their hands.

"It's ok to be white" only works as a slogan for white supremacists if there actually IS widespread racial animosity against whites.

Comment: @Ryan_L Even if that's true, most people who answer a poll won't be metagaming how their enemies could exploit the results. I imagine a number of respondents saw the question and either recognised it as a white supremacist slogan or just thought it sounded a bit iffy, and so either picked no, answered "don't know", or just refused to fill in the survey.

Comment: @Ryan_L It would help legitimize white supremacist groups who use the slogan. Big rallies of people holding banners saying "it's okay to be white". Half the people there would be Nazis, but if questioned, they'd challenge that by pointing to the poll saying their innocuous slogan is universally agreed with. You may compare other relatively innocuous slogans that got used by bad groups, like "Make America great again!" ... or "Deutschland uber alles!"